# Set element at arbitrary index in list in Python?

Tags: python

I am aware that with lists in Python, you typically can *not* set the value of an element in list at an arbitrary index; in this example, even if I try inserting at index 5 of a newly created list, I simply get the value appended at next available index:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 11:59:41)  [GCC 10.1.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> aa=[]
>>> aa[0]=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>> aa.insert(5, 100)
>>> aa
[100]
>>> aa.insert(5, 100)
>>> aa
[100, 100]
```

However, let's say I have pairs like "3:17", "5:72" etc, where the first number is index, and the second number is value - which come in randomly from some source (let's say a database), and I'd like to populate a list with these.

Ideally, I would imagine a method, let's call is `pseudoset`, which would have a signature like:

```
list.pseudoset(index, value, value-for-not-yet-existing-indices)
```

... so if we have:

```
mylist = []
mylist.pseudoset(3, 17, None)
```

... I would end up with `mylist` being `[None, None, None, 17]`; and if after that I issue:

```
mylist.pseudoset(5, 72, None)
```

... I would end up with `mylist` being `[None, None, None, 17, None, 72]`; and if after that I try:

```
mylist.pseudoset(1, 32, None)
```

... I would end up with `mylist` being `[None, 32, None, 17, None, 72]`.

However, I am not aware of a method of `list` like this in Python.

Here is this example as (failing) code, using `insert` instead:

```py
incoming_data = [ "3:17", "5:72", "1:32" ]

incoming_list = []
for pair in incoming_data:
  lpair = pair.split(":")
  theindex = int( lpair[0] )
  thevalue = int( lpair[1] )
  incoming_list.insert(theindex, thevalue)

print(incoming_list) # prints: [17, 32, 72]
```

So, here, the output is `[17, 32, 72]`, but it should be `[None, 32, None, 17, None, 72]` (or whatever arbitrary value other than `None`, for the unspecified/not-yet-specified elements of the list). Also, the final output should be a `list`, not an `OrderedDict` or some other class.

Can I do this in Python - and if so, how?

Comment: add dummy items first until the size of the list is big enough for index `theindex` to be valid, why not use a `dict()`

Comment: "you typically can not set the value of an element in list at an arbitrary index;" yes you can. But the index must exist for you to do it. `.insert` is not how you typically set values in a list, and has the semantics that are described in it's documentation (out of bounds get appended to the end). Normally, you set an index by doing `mylist[index] = value`,

Comment: It sounds to me you should use a `dict`, and then at the end, create a list from that dict.

Comment: Thanks @RiccardoBucco - that indeed seems to answer my question!

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga - I am aware of `mylist[index] = value`, however that fails immediately in this context with `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`, as the first snippet in OP shows; I just used `insert` as a way to illustrate what I need (albeit producing wrong results).

Comment: can you not sort the list in ascending order. Then start iterating through the list till the max value of the final item in the list? For example, when you sort this value, the last item will have xx:yy where xx is the last value. So you create a for loop and add into the list. Wouldnt that be an easy way to do it?

Comment: Initialize list with None and Replace the element None based on the index in the string

    incoming_data = [ "3:17", "5:72", "1:32" ]
    
    incoming_list = [None] * (len(incoming_data)*2)
    for pair in incoming_data:
      lpair = pair.split(":")
      theindex = int( lpair[0] )
      thevalue = int( lpair[1] )
      incoming_list[theindex] = thevalue
    
    print(incoming_list)

Output:

    [None, 32, None, 17, None, 72]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a dict then convert to the list you need:

```
>>> incoming_data = [ "3:17", "5:72", "1:32" ]
>>> data = {}
>>> for item in incoming_data:
...     i, value = map(int, item.split(':'))
...     data[i] = value
...
>>> data
{3: 17, 5: 72, 1: 32}
>>> max_i = max(data)
>>> data = [data.get(i, 'default') for i in range(max_i + 1)]
>>> data
['default', 32, 'default', 17, 'default', 72]
```

Comment: Thanks - was not aware of `data.get(i, 'default')` in lists, which is why I found the conversion of dict to list difficult, and which is why I asked this question.

Comment: @sdbbs well, that's in dicts

Comment: @Kaushal this solution doesn't rely on dict objects preserving order, and in any case, dict objects in python 3.7+ *do* preserve order

Comment: @Kaushal - you're right, dict does not preserve order, however, the .get retrieves a key that happens to be integer, the `for i in range` guarantees the order, I think.

Comment: @sdbbs they do in 3.7+ (and in CPython 3.6 as an implementation detail)